# How is it "easily checked" that $[1-s(\cos\theta + i \sin \theta)] \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n [\cos(n\theta)+i \sin(n\theta)] = 1$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, probability-theory, generating-functions

This is from a derivation of de Moivre's theorem on p.148 of Grimmett & Stirzaker's *Probability and Random Processes*.

The setup:

> The sequence $a_n = (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^n$ has generating function
>   $$G_a(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ s(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta) \right]^n = \frac{1}{1 - s(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)}$$
>   if $|s| < 1$; here $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

The part that I don't follow:

> It is easily checked by examining the coefficient of $s^n$ that $$\left[1-s(\cos\theta + i \sin \theta) \right] \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n \left[\cos(n\theta)+i \sin(n\theta) \right] = 1 $$ when $|s| < 1$.

The rest is clear to me, but in case you're interested:

> Thus $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n \left[\cos(n\theta)+i \sin(n\theta) \right] = \frac{1}{1-s(\cos\theta + i \sin \theta)}$$ if $|s| < 1$. Equating the coefficients of $s_n$ we obtain the well-known fact that $\cos(n\theta)+i \sin(n\theta) = (\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)^n$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Once you know $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$, this is just the geometric series, since the sum on the left side of your last equation is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (se^{i\theta})^n$. Equivalently without explicit reference to complex exponentials, you can view this as an application of de Moivre's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the left-hand side. The $s^0$ coefficient is clearly $1$. For $n>0$ the $s^n$ coefficient is$$\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta-(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos(n-1)\theta+i\sin(n-1)\theta),$$which you can verify is zero with compound angle formulae.

Comment: One would expect the author to have been more explicit about this.... It seems very roundabout anyway.

Comment: @Chris The author already mentioned "**by examining the coefficient of $s^n$**" in the second box. It is quite explicit I'd say.

Comment: @kennytm Maybe; but I didn't think the quoted text in the OP was clear about leading the reader to do the computation that J.G. did. I found it roundabout because it seemed like a more convoluted way to establish de Moivre's theorem than simple induction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use geometric series, although this is perhaps not the same as comparing coefficients so it may not be what you want. E.g. we wish to show that
$$\left[1-s(\cos\theta + i \sin \theta) \right] \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n \left[\cos(n\theta)+i \sin(n\theta) \right] = 1.$$
Euler's formula states that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, and De Moivre's theorem basically uses the fact that $(e^x)^n=e^{nx}$ combined with Euler's formula. So we have:
$$(1-se^{i\theta})\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^ne^{in\theta}=1.$$
The summand is the same as $(se^{i\theta})^n$, so by geometric series we have $$(1-se^{i\theta})\frac{1}{1-se^{i\theta}}=1,$$ as was to be proved.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the geometric series $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n = \dfrac{1}{1-x}, |x| < 1$.